# Error following AutoForm email example: ReferenceError: check is not defined

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Working on a comment form in meteor using autoform.

```
METEOR@1.4.2.3
aldeed:autoform
```

From the autoform docs, this is my server side function to send an email using the form:

```
Meteor.methods({
 sendRequestEmail: function(doc) {
  console.log("Sending request email...");
  // Important server-side check for security and data integrity
  check(doc, Schemas.RequestForm);

  // Build the e-mail text
  var text = "Name: " + doc.name + "\n\n" +
             "Email: " + doc.email + "\n\n\n\n" +
             doc.message;

  this.unblock();

  // Send the e-mail
  Email.send({
    to: "user@site.com",
    from: doc.email,
    subject: doc.name + " request",
    text: text
  });
 }
});
```

But here is the error I'm getting in the server console:

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendRequestEmail' ReferenceError: check is not defined
 at [object Object].sendRequestEmail (server/main.js:13:5)
 at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1711:12)
 at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19
 at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1122:17)
 at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:709:40
 at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1122:17)
 at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:707:46
 at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:681:23)
 at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:551:43
```

Is check not part of autoform?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, no check is not part of autoform. Here's the easy fix:

```
> meteor add check
```

Whew!